# .NET access to DB2 in windows 8

Tags: .net, ado.net, windows-8, db2

In windows 7 I was able to connect to DB2 using IBM's DB2 driver, however this doesn't seem to work with windows 8. The installation of the client drivers fails with the following:

> MSI (c) (0C:18) [11:47:20:731]: Windows Installer installed the
>   product. Product Name: IBM Data Server Driver Package - IBMDBCL1.
>   Product Version: 10.1.0.872. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer:
>   IBM. Installation success or error status: 1603.

I've also tried the MS OLEDB driver for DB2 which also didn't appear to work with windows 8 (fails to install as well).

Are there any other alternatives (such as beta drivers) or has anyone else had any success connecting to DB2 from a Windows 8 machine?

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message? It doesn't work is a bit vague

Comment: @steve Sorry, that is unclear the install fails. See the error message in the question

Comment: @LukeMcGregor how did you go with this? Any luck installing it on windows 8? I have the same issue.

Comment: @ysrb yeah IBM released some docs around how to do this a little while ago (we actually just worked it out for ourselves at the time) but the docs do work. They are pretty fiddly though, see my answer below.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Thanks Luke for sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM has recently released some docs on how to make their drivers work on Windows 8/Server 2012. Unfortunately this requires some registry hacks and GAC fiddling which is pretty unideal, but it does actually work.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21618434